# How to apply a cumulative function pandas dataframe but restart the cumulative function when a different column changes?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, finance

This is a pretty hard question to me. The answer might come simply to fresh eyes, but I'm stuck. Basically, I have a dataframe of bulk balance sheets from simfin.com. I want to get the percent change in the `Retained Earnings` column, but restart the accumulation at each new ticker.

```
      Ticker  Fiscal Year Fiscal Period  Retained Earnings
0          A         2016            Q1       5.666000e+09
1          A         2016            Q2       5.720000e+09
2          A         2016            Q3       6.000000e+09
3          A         2016            Q4       6.089000e+09
4          A         2017            Q1      -4.530000e+08
...      ...          ...           ...                ...
36669   ZYXI         2019            Q3       1.140900e+07
36670   ZYXI         2019            Q4       1.435600e+07
36671   ZYXI         2020            Q1       1.729300e+07
36672   ZYXI         2020            Q2       2.031000e+07
36673   ZYXI         2020            Q3       2.164300e+07
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could do something with grouping by the ticker and computing the cumulative change in each group, then concatenating the results together?

Comment: Try `df.groupby('Ticker')['Retained Earnings'].pct_change()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
data["Retained Earnings pct change"] = data.groupby("Ticker")["Retained Earnings"].pct_change()
```

Thanks Scott for the help.